# Communication between process using Distributed Object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ipc, distributed-objects

I can't manage to vend proxy object, it just stuck on client side when try to get connection

```
NSConnection *conn = [NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:@"server"  host:nil];
```

Here is how I register connection and vend object

```
//server
-(void)initServer {

NSConnection * connection = [[NSConnection alloc]init];

MZRemoteObject * obj = [[MZRemoteObject alloc]init];
obj.message = @"hello world";
[connection setRootObject:obj];
if([connection registerName:@"server"]== NO){
    NSLog(@"error Register Server");
}
NSLog(@"Registered Server");
}
```

Client side(getting vended object)

```
- (void)recieveMessage {

NSDistantObject *proxy;
NSConnection *conn = [NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:@"server"  host:nil];

if (!conn) {
    NSLog(@"conn recieve message error");
}

proxy = [conn rootProxy];
MZRemoteObject * obj =(MZRemoteObject*)proxy;

if (!proxy) {
    NSLog(@"proxy,recieve message error");
}
NSLog(@"----%@",obj.message);
}
```

Could any one tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you calling initServer from thread ?

Comment: I call both methods from main thread, but from diferent apps Client app and Server app

Comment: Are you sandboxed? Is the server an actual application, rather than, say, a command-line tool? Is anything written to the console log? Have you considered using the `+serviceConnectionWithName:rootObject:` and `+rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName:host:` convenience constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

Start the current runloop in -(void)initServer method.

```
-(void)initServer {

NSConnection * connection = [[NSConnection alloc]init];

MZRemoteObject * obj = [[MZRemoteObject alloc]init];
obj.message = @"hello world";
[connection setRootObject:obj];
if([connection registerName:@"server"]== NO){
    NSLog(@"error Register Server");
}
NSLog(@"Registered Server");
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];  
}
```